# Custom Column in pinscript strategy List of Trades

Tags: pine-script-v5

Just wondering. is it possible to add custom column in the List of Trades in pinescript strategy?

By default it only has these columns:
[image]

It would be very helpful just incase someone needs additional parameters to their study.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Strategy Tester tab could not be customized, unfortunately :(

Comment: @e2e4 Thanks for the reply. That's sad to hear. hope Tradingview would add this feature.